# jboss 5.1 cannot startup after deployment migrate from 4.0.3sp1

Tags: jboss5.x

I am trying to migrate deployment from 4.0.3sp1 to 5.1. I just copied the file under `/opt/jboss/server` to jboss 5.1 directory. 
At first, it prompt failed to access server/conf/bootstrap.xml, etc, I copied them from `/opt/jboss/server/default/conf/*.xml`, then it come to the error:

```
14:27:19,785 ERROR [ScopedProfileServiceController] Error installing to Create: name=ProfileKey@92eb76[domain=default, server=default, name=bindings] state=Configured mode=On Demand requiredState=Installed
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Child not found bindingservice.beans/ for FileHandler@15606014[path= context=file:/opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/...

Failed to boot JBoss:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incompletely deployed:

*** PROFILES IN ERROR: Name -> Error
Profile: ProfileKey@92eb76[domain=default, server=default, name=bindings] in error due to java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

is there any difference on configuration files between 4.0.3sp1 and 5.1? anything I need to add in jboss 5.1 server//conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I undarstand you correctly but you cannot just copy profile between JBoss version. Between version 4.0.3 and 5.1 was a lot of changes and I really doubt if something like that can work (for example theres is a lot of different services, configuration changes, completely different kernel and so one).

Since JBoss 5 there is new way for setting port bindings and I believe that JBoss cannot find these configuration file.

If you want migrate to knew version of JBoss you should use for some JBoss 5.1 profile: `default` or `all` and in that profile install your application, data sources and other things.

Comment: Thanks for response. i have not copied the configuration files from 4.0.3sp1, i mean i copied the bootstrap.xml, profile.xml from 5.1 default/conf to myserver/conf, because i met error said jboss can not find these configuration files, because as you know, in jboss 4.0.3sp1, there are even no these configuration files, so i have no these conf files in my 4.0.3sp1 deployment.

Comment: which configuration file you mean is for "new way for setting port bindings"? and could you help to give me one example for jboss 5.1? 
many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This issue is because of missing myserver/conf/bindingservice.beans, i copied this folder from jboss 5.1 server/default/conf/bindingservice.beans, now this issue is gone.